# Sollte es is meaning should or if

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german

What is this meaning:

> Sollte es Ihnen nicht besser gehen, kommen Sie bitte in drei Tagen hierher.

When I want to translate this sentence I replace "sollte es" with "if".
Why we dont use "wenn" ?

Refrence (wortschatz & grammatik A2 Heuber)

Comment: Do you miss a word in your sentence? Shouldn't it be "Sollte es Ihnen nicht besser *gehen*, kommen Sie bitte in drei Tagen hierher"?

Comment: @planetmaker: I have edited that.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said already, this verb-initial construction is interpreted as a conditional. In principle, such constructions also exist in English. An example is: "*Had I known that before going out,* I wouldn't have worn sandals" (picked from https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V1-Stellung#Sprachvergleichende_Aspekte ). The wikipedia article in the link lists further cases of German verb-initial clauses with other interpretations besides conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use one of

> Wenn es Ihnen nicht besser geht, kommen Sie bitte in drei Tagen hierher.

> Falls es Ihnen nicht besser geht, kommen Sie bitte in drei Tagen hierher.

Both can be translated as

> If you don't feel better, ...

while *"falls"* can also mean

> *In case* you don't feel better, ...

The variant with "wenn" is more neutral while "falls" carries the assumption that the case is unlikely.

The wording

> Sollte es Ihnen nicht besser gehen, ...

carries an even stronger expectation that you *will* feel better.

Answer (score 0):

By putting the finite verb in front of a clause, you turn that clause into a yes-no-question or into a conditional clause equivalent to the question:

> Hilfst du mir? Dann helf ich dir.
>
> Hilfst du mir, helf ich dir.

*Do you help me? I help you then.*

That latter sentence consists of a conditional clause that acts as a dependent clause to the following main clause. The meaning is the same as

> Falls du mir hilfst, helf ich dir.

Note that in German, conditionals don't have to be put in Konjunktiv (subjunctive) mood. It's perfectly okay to phrase them in indicative mood. They are about factual decisions then.

Your example employs Konjunktiv II mood for *sollen*, which makes it purely hypothetical.